# How to get an element with class after current one in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is the sample html code:

```
<div id="current_element">Current element</div>
Many unknown tags...
<div class="target">This is target element</div>
Many other tags...
```

Note That Target element and current element may not under the same parent, so I can't find it with .nextAll('.target'), right?

Are there any **simple** way to find it? Thanks!

Comment: but they ARE under the same parent if they're just one after one?

Comment: See code below for example:

    <div id="area1"><div id="current_element">Current</div></div>
    
    <div id="area2"><div class="target">Target</div></div>

They are not under same parent right?

Comment: So how do you know which element is the target? Please explain the rule clearly, then that should lead you to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You html in the comment is different to the one in the question

```
<div id="area1">
  <div id="current_element">Current</div>
</div>
<div id="area2">
  <div class="target">Target</div>
</div>
```

What I would do is to wrap them with a div:

```
<div id="mainparent">
  <div id="area1">
    <div id="current_element">Current</div>
  </div>
  <div id="area2">
    <div class="target">Target</div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Then I go back and find the other child:

```
//this = .current_element
var $target = $(this).closest("#mainparent").find(".target");
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 10):

Since elemenets are returned in document order, you can use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to find the next one in  a set containing both, like this:

```
var ce = $("#current_element"), all = $("#current_element, .target");
var target = all.eq(all.index(ce)+1);
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6bjpL/).

Comment: +1 I used this in something I wrote and it worked as a charm for me, thanks. Credit given in the comments in my code.